# Should methods and members of Actor be defined as private

Tags: scala, actor

What is the best practice when defining an actor?

- Actor state: is it better to define a "var" with a collection like in the code below or is it better to define a "val" with mutable collection ? should we define it as private ?
- should we define methods of Actor as private ?

```scala
class FooActor(out:ActorRef)extends Actor {
    private var words:List[String] = Nil
    override def receive: Receive = ???
    def foo()=???
}
```

Comment: One of the main purposes of actors is to allow you to isolate mutable state from the rest of your program and thus preserve referential transparency. Therefore it really doesn't matter whether you use a (var) immutable collection or a (val) mutable collection. I'm pretty sure that the methods that you define in an actor are effectively private anyway, although I will leave it to someone more expert to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

On the first point, generally, I would go with neither. Instead, set the `receive` method to a method taking the collection as a parameter, and update the actor's state when the collection changes using [`context.become(...)`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Become_Unbecome). Eg:

```
class FooActor(out:ActorRef)extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = active(Nil)

  def active(words:List[String]): Receive = Receive {
    case word_to_add: String => context.become(active(word_to_add :: words))
    case ...
  }

  private def foo()=???
}
```

On the second point, any helper methods are probably only for the actor's own use, so make them private.

Comment: nice FP approach. Is that also efficient with dealing with large states ? say 100K messages  (like @nattyddubs mentioned )

Comment: @igx `context.become` is essentially using a closure in place of a class field so expect the same pros/cons as using an immutable `var` field. Note that `context.become(..., discardOld = false)` will behave like a stack of states which has other performance impliciations.

Comment: @dwickern IIUC . when handling large size collection using mutable var to handle state have better memory implication than using "become" as Shadowlands described . correct ?

Comment: @igx I don't think the efficiency of the data type used is likely to be that significant. Memory-wise I would expect they would be comparable, and time-wise, any differences are likely to be swamped by the time cost of the actor system routing and handling messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

To the first point it really depends on how large the collection of items is going to be that you're mutating. Are you going to be adding 100k items to a `Map` over the course of 100k messages? If this is the case perhaps you should be using a mutable collection so as to avoid the overhead of copying the entire collection to add each item. Make a smart decision based on the use case.

**Here's a reference to the performance of mutable vs. immutable collections**: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

To the second point the visibility of the methods doesn't matter in terms of the interface with the `Actor`. The only way that you **should** be interacting with an `Actor` is through asking and telling messages so the visibility of any member methods is of little consequence outside of inferring purpose to the reader.

Comment: AFAIK adding and item to immutable collection use memory shared data rather then coping the data . isn't it ?

Comment: It has to do with the data structure involved. I'd assume that prepending a`List` would not copy all of the items since it's using a `LinkedList` under the covers.